# Getting pdf file from URL in Pdf JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, pdf.js

i am working on a project which user can preview pdf before uploading.
i successfully created the script to preview pdf file from   with the help this javascript pdf library  https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/index.html#interactive-examples

but i needed to make a page where user can edit details and i want them to still preview the uploaded pdf file

here is the code to preview pdf file from form input

```
function preview(id, pageNumber = 1) {
    // var file = i.files[0}
    var input = document.getElementById(id);

    
    var file = input.files[0];
    if (file.type == "application/pdf") {
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function() {
            var pdfData = new Uint8Array(this.result);

            // Using DocumentInitParameters object to load binary data.
            var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({
                data: pdfData
            });
            loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {

                console.log('PDF loaded');
            
                // Fetch the first page
                // var pageNumber = 1;
                pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
                    console.log('Page loaded');

                    var scale = 1.5;
                    var viewport = page.getViewport({
                        scale: scale
                    });

                    // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
                    var canvas = $("#pdfViewer")[0];
                    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    canvas.height = viewport.height;
                    canvas.width = viewport.width;

                    // Render PDF page into canvas context
                    var renderContext = {
                        canvasContext: context,
                        viewport: viewport
                    };
                    var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
                    renderTask.promise.then(function() {
                        console.log('Page rendered');
                    });
                });
            }, function(reason) {
                // PDF loading error
                console.error(reason);
            });
        };
        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }

}
```

here is the html sample

```
<input type="file" class="form-control mb-3" name="file" id="myPdf" required>
                        
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#myPdf").on("change", function(e) {
    preview('myPdf', 1);
});
</script>
```

Question is
**How will i use this code but collect file from url instead of form input**

Thanks for your responses